# Fundamental Groups of Complements of Knots Algorithm

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is there any clear algorithm to compute the fundamental group of complements of knots?

Comment: What do you mean by "compute"? There is the Wirtinger presentation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_presentation) but it is unclear what information you can extract from it in general.

Comment: There's also an algorithm to construct a triangulation of the complement, from which there's a standard $\pi_1$ presentation construction.

Comment: the Wirtinger presentation was what I was looking for... Thanks guys